# How do I store credentials so I do not need to authenticate to a server each time?

Tags: iphone

I just finished implementing my first iPhone application , everything went well, now I need to supply a sort of security to my application and I don't know what is the best way to do that ?

Currently it works
like this : the user enters his user name and password , the server verifies that this is the correct information , when  I  made another request to the server it asks for a user name and password so it returns to the method named didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge.  I provide the user name and password again , the server verifies that, and sends the request again.

My questions are : Is this  a correct behavior? is there any kind of session for iphone? And how can I use cookies to save user name and password ?

Also I stored 
newCredential = [NSURLCredential 
                         credentialWithUser:username password:password
                         persistence:**NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession**];

But it not stored for session.  Is there problem in my code on the iPhone or the PHP script that we are calling?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [Keychain API](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code) to store and retrieve credentials securely. This will even preserve credentials between application restarts, if this is desirable.

Comment: Using: NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent

Credential will be stored in the user’s keychain and shared with other applications.

Comment: I also tried NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent but not stored if I call the next webURL using the initwithrequestmethod or POST method .
when i tried on the browser firefox it doeesn`t ask for credentials again but on mac safari it ask .
Is the problem with the webscript .